# How to set console font?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

How can I set a unicode font for console? I tried the following but I get an AV on the line `GetCurrentConsoleFontEx`.

```
program ConsoleVsUnicode;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Winapi.Windows,
  System.SysUtils;

type
  COORD = record
    X, Y: smallint;
  end;

  TCONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX = record
    cbSize: cardinal;
    nFont: longword;
    dwFontSize: COORD;
    FontFamily: cardinal;
    FontWeight: cardinal;
    FaceName: array [0 .. LF_FACESIZE - 1] of WideChar;
  end;

  PCONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX = ^TCONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX;

function SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(ConsoleOutput: THandle; MaximumWindow: BOOL; ConsoleInfo: PCONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX): BOOL; external kernel32 name 'SetCurrentConsoleFontEx';
function GetCurrentConsoleFontEx(ConsoleOutput: THandle; MaximumWindow: BOOL; ConsoleInfo: PCONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX): BOOL; external kernel32 name 'GetCurrentConsoleFontEx';

procedure SetConsoleFont(const AFontSize: word);
var
  ci: TCONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX;
  ch: THandle;
begin
  if NOT CheckWin32Version(6, 0) then
  EXIT;

  FillChar(ci, SizeOf(TCONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX), 0);
  ci.cbSize := SizeOf(TCONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX);

  ch := GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
  GetCurrentConsoleFontEx(ch, FALSE, @ci); // AV Here!

  ci.FontFamily := FF_DONTCARE;
  // ci.FaceName:= 'Lucida Console';
  ci.FaceName := 'Consolas';
  ci.dwFontSize.X := 0;
  ci.dwFontSize.Y := AFontSize;
  ci.FontWeight := FW_BOLD;
  SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(ch, FALSE, @ci);

end;

begin
  SetConsoleFont(32);
  ReadLn;

end.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These functions use the `stdcall` calling convention. You'll need to add that the their declaration.

```
function SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(ConsoleOutput: THandle; MaximumWindow: BOOL;
  ConsoleInfo: PCONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX): BOOL; stdcall;
  external kernel32 name 'SetCurrentConsoleFontEx';
function GetCurrentConsoleFontEx(ConsoleOutput: THandle; MaximumWindow: BOOL;
  ConsoleInfo: PCONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX): BOOL; stdcall;
  external kernel32 name 'GetCurrentConsoleFontEx';
```

You should also check the return values of these API calls. For instance, using `Win32Check` would be appropriate.

As an aside, the call to `CheckWin32Version` is pointless. If the API functions that you import are not present in `kernel32.dll` then the program will not even load. You could use delay loading to get around that and support XP, if XP support is indeed desirable to you.

One final comment is that the struct parameter to these functions is not optional. In which case converting to `const` and `var` makes the function call a little more convenient.

```
function SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(ConsoleOutput: THandle; MaximumWindow: BOOL;
  const ConsoleInfo: TCONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX): BOOL; stdcall;
  external kernel32 name 'SetCurrentConsoleFontEx';
function GetCurrentConsoleFontEx(ConsoleOutput: THandle; MaximumWindow: BOOL;
  var ConsoleInfo: TCONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX): BOOL; stdcall;
  external kernel32 name 'GetCurrentConsoleFontEx';
```

---

A more fundamental problem that you will face is that Delphi's console output functions do not support Unicode. Changing fonts won't change that. Nothing is going to get Delphi to deal with Unicode text when you call `Write`.

To output Unicode text from Delphi, you'll need to go direct to the Windows console API. For instance, `WriteConsoleW`.

Even that won't help you with characters that require surrogate pairs, such as Chinese text. The console API is still limited to UCS2 and so if your text has surrogate pairs you are simply out of luck.

---

**Update**

According to [TOndrej's answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265018/unicode-console-application-in-delphi-2009/268202#268202), you can produce Unicode output from `Write` by:

1. Setting the console code page to UTF-8 with `SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8)`, and
2. Passing UTF-8 encoded 8 bit text to `Write` by making use of `UTF8Encode`.

However, I believe that you will still not get past the lack of UTF-16 surrogate pair support for text outside the BMP.

Comment: How about delayed loading?

Comment: @user3841593 Yes, I already mentioned that, but that's really orthogonal to the question

Comment: The problem with this implementation is that this still will not output chinese characters.

Comment: I took your question to be how to resolve the access violation. I cannot see anywhere in the question where you attempt to write to the console.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks. I'll ask it in another question.

Comment: @user3841593 I've already dealt with it in an update to this answer. In summary, `Write` is not going to be of any use to you. You need to use Win32 API directly. You might find it more productive to link to `msvcrt.dll` and use its console support!

Comment: Yup, that gets it done. It won't handle Chinese I suspect. If I recall correctly the console is still UCS2 and Chinese characters require surrogate pairs.

Comment: You can use SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8) as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265018/unicode-console-application-in-delphi-2009/268202#268202).