# Is Writeln capable of supporting Unicode?

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-xe7

Consider this program:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

begin
  Writeln('АБВГДЕЖЅZЗИІКЛМНОПҀРСТȢѸФХѾЦЧШЩЪЫЬѢѤЮѦѪѨѬѠѺѮѰѲѴ');
end.
```

The output on my console which uses the Consolas font is:

```
????????Z??????????????????????????????????????
```

The Windows console is quite capable of supporting Unicode as evidenced by this program:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Winapi.Windows;

const
  Text = 'АБВГДЕЖЅZЗИІКЛМНОПҀРСТȢѸФХѾЦЧШЩЪЫЬѢѤЮѦѪѨѬѠѺѮѰѲѴ';

var
  NumWritten: DWORD;

begin
  WriteConsole(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), PChar(Text), Length(Text), NumWritten, nil);
end.
```

for which the output is:

```
АБВГДЕЖЅZЗИІКЛМНОПҀРСТȢѸФХѾЦЧШЩЪЫЬѢѤЮѦѪѨѬѠѺѮѰѲѴ
```

Can `Writeln` be persuaded to respect Unicode, or is it inherently crippled?

Comment: [`Possible duplicate`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/265018/960757) ? I think [`TOndrej's answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/268202/960757) covers your question.

Comment: @TLama I saw that question. I think this is different. I want to know if there is some way to make Writeln respect Unicode. Perhaps through an RTL function call the switches behaviour.

Comment: Just hints: http://www.bobswart.nl/Weblog/Blog.aspx?RootId=5:3011 . Also: http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/39022

Comment: `SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);` works, but is not the answer you are looking for?

Comment: @LURD Is that enough? Does the RTL convert UTF-16 to UTF-8 or do you have to? In any case it feels wrong to have to frab code pages. I do wonder what Emba were thinking.

Comment: If I use `SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8)`, then *most* of the string looks OK, but there are a few "box" characters near the end, so that is not perfect. I also tried `SetTextCodePage(Output, 1200)`, but that gives me lots of weird symbols, and a string like `'1200'` is displayed as `1 2 0 0`, so that can't be it either.

Comment: Also, for character set support outside the space covered by the default console fonts, see : http://stackoverflow.com/a/21753872/327083

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just set the console output codepage through the `SetConsoleOutputCP()` routine with codepage `cp_UTF8`.

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils,Windows;
Const
  Text =  'АБВГДЕЖЅZЗИІКЛМНОПҀРСТȢѸФХѾЦЧШЩЪЫЬѢѤЮѦѪѨѬѠѺѮѰѲѴ';
VAR
  NumWritten: DWORD;
begin
  ReadLn;  // Make sure Consolas font is selected
  try
    WriteConsole(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), PChar(Text), Length(Text), NumWritten, nil);    
    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
    WriteLn;
    WriteLn('АБВГДЕЖЅZЗИІКЛМНОПҀРСТȢѸФХѾЦЧШЩЪЫЬѢѤЮѦѪѨѬѠѺѮѰѲѴ');
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Outputs:

```
АБВГДЕЖЅZЗИІКЛМНОПҀРСТȢѸФХѾЦЧШЩЪЫЬѢѤЮѦѪѨѬѠѺѮѰѲѴ
АБВГДЕЖЅZЗИІКЛМНОПҀРСТȢѸФХѾЦЧШЩЪЫЬѢѤЮѦѪѨѬѠѺѮѰѲѴ
```

`WriteLn()` translates Unicode UTF16 strings to the selected output codepage (cp_UTF8) internally.

---

Update:

The above works in Delphi-XE2 and above.
In Delphi-XE you need an explicit conversion to UTF-8 to make it work properly.

```
WriteLn(UTF8String('АБВГДЕЖЅZЗИІКЛМНОПҀРСТȢѸФХѾЦЧШЩЪЫЬѢѤЮѦѪѨѬѠѺѮѰѲѴ'));
```

---

**Addendum:**

If an output to the console is done in another codepage before calling `SetConsoleOutputCP(cp_UTF8)`,
the OS will not correctly output text in `utf-8`.
This can be fixed by closing/reopening the stdout handler.

Another option is to declare a new text output handler for `utf-8`.

```
var
  toutUTF8: TextFile;
...
SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
AssignFile(toutUTF8,'',cp_UTF8);  // Works in XE2 and above
Rewrite(toutUTF8);
WriteLn(toutUTF8,'АБВГДЕЖЅZЗИІКЛМНОПҀРСТȢѸФХѾЦЧШЩЪЫЬѢѤЮѦѪѨѬѠѺѮѰѲѴ');
```

Comment: @user246408, tested in XE5 and XE7.

Comment: @user246408 I tested this in XE3. It's a decent workaround (+1), but I'd  be concerned about changing the code page. At the very least I'd want to change it back when the process detached from the console.

Comment: Does not work in Delphi XE; requires explicit cast to UTF8String.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I think you should be able to get the actual code page by using `GetConsoleOutputCP` before doing the change and change it back after. Check the (great) answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259084/what-encoding-code-page-is-cmd-exe-using).

Comment: @GuillemVicens Sure. I'd probably want to use `SetConsoleCtrlHandler` to make sure that the restoration happened even for abnormal termination.

Comment: This does not look correct in my German console window, so something is wrong here. Could of course be my font, so I'll try with another.

Comment: Ok, changing the font from Lucida Console to Consolas made it look OK.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, when using MinWidth specifier, the RTL does not take into account the code points. This will make it hard to format the output. `WriteLn('АБ':4);` gives zero padding since Length('АБ') is 4 in an utf-8 string.

Comment: I guess the necessary information would be available to `AlternateWriteUnicodeStringProc`.

Comment: Testing in XE2 I found it fails if the first `WriteLn;` is called before, not after `SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);`  What is that all about?

Comment: @HughJones, I also saw this. My theory is that once an output is done in a locale, all attempts to change the codepage is swallowed by the OS. I'm searching for documentation, but I have seen this confirmed in other forums.

Answer (score 12):

The `System` unit declares a variable named `AlternateWriteUnicodeStringProc` that allows customisation of how `Writeln` performs output. This program:

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Winapi.Windows;

function MyAlternateWriteUnicodeStringProc(var t: TTextRec; s: UnicodeString): Pointer;
var
  NumberOfCharsWritten, NumOfBytesWritten: DWORD;
begin
  Result := @t;
  if t.Handle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE) then
    WriteConsole(t.Handle, Pointer(s), Length(s), NumberOfCharsWritten, nil)
  else
    WriteFile(t.Handle, Pointer(s)^, Length(s)*SizeOf(WideChar), NumOfBytesWritten, nil);
end;

var
  UserFile: Text;

begin
  AlternateWriteUnicodeStringProc := MyAlternateWriteUnicodeStringProc;
  Writeln('АБВГДЕЖЅZЗИІКЛМНОПҀРСТȢѸФХѾЦЧШЩЪЫЬѢѤЮѦѪѨѬѠѺѮѰѲѴ');
  Readln;
end.
```

produces this output:

```
АБВГДЕЖЅZЗИІКЛМНОПҀРСТȢѸФХѾЦЧШЩЪЫЬѢѤЮѦѪѨѬѠѺѮѰѲѴ
```

I'm sceptical of how I've implemented `MyAlternateWriteUnicodeStringProc` and how it would interact with classic Pascal I/O. However, it appears to behave as desired for output to the console.

The documentation of [`AlternateWriteUnicodeStringProc`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.AlternateWriteUnicodeStringProc) currently says, wait for it, ...

> Embarcadero Technologies does not currently have any additional information. Please help us document this topic by using the Discussion page!

Comment: @user246408 Can you expand? What does not work in XE? Is `AlternateWriteUnicodeStringProc` not present in XE?

Comment: @user246408 The D2010 `_WriteUString` begins `// !!! FIXME` and has no reference to `AlternateWriteUnicodeStringProc` so I guess that's what you are referring to

Comment: yes no such identifier, compile time error; FIXME I believe because it does not even respect ANSI system codepage; console localization seems to be totally broken.

Comment: In XE2 codepage support was introduced to the `WriteLn(F, ...` version (where F is a `TextFile`), see also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14232900/unicode-text-file-output-differs-between-xe2-and-delphi-2009

Comment: So I guess Emba decided to introduce this `AlternateWriteUnicodeStringProc` in XE2, too.

Comment: For output redirection support you have to check the return code of WriteConsole and then call WriteFile instead.

Comment: Works perfectly for me on XE10.1 (Berlin).

Answer (score 5):

`WriteConsoleW` seems to be a quite magical function.

```
procedure WriteLnToConsoleUsingWriteFile(CP: Cardinal; AEncoding: TEncoding; const S: string);
var
  Buffer: TBytes;
  NumWritten: Cardinal;
begin
  Buffer := AEncoding.GetBytes(S);
  // This is a side effect and should be avoided ...
  SetConsoleOutputCP(CP);
  WriteFile(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), Buffer[0], Length(Buffer), NumWritten, nil);
  WriteLn;
end;

procedure WriteLnToConsoleUsingWriteConsole(const S: string);
var
  NumWritten: Cardinal;
begin
  WriteConsole(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), PChar(S), Length(S), NumWritten, nil);
  WriteLn;
end;

const
  Text = 'АБВГДЕЖЅZЗИІКЛМНОПҀРСТȢѸФХѾЦЧШЩЪЫЬѢѤЮѦѪѨѬѠѺѮѰѲѴ';
begin
  ReadLn; // Make sure Consolas font is selected
  // Works, but changing the console CP is neccessary
  WriteLnToConsoleUsingWriteFile(CP_UTF8, TEncoding.UTF8, Text);
  // Doesn't work
  WriteLnToConsoleUsingWriteFile(1200, TEncoding.Unicode, Text);
  // This does and doesn't need the CP anymore
  WriteLnToConsoleUsingWriteConsole(Text);
  ReadLn;
end.
```

So in summary:

`WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), ...)` supports UTF-16.

`WriteFile(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), ...)` doesn't support UTF-16.

My guess would be that in order to support different ANSI encodings the classic Pascal I/O uses the `WriteFile` call.

Also keep in mind that when used on a **file** instead of the console it has to work as well:

[unicode text file output differs between XE2 and Delphi 2009?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14232900/unicode-text-file-output-differs-between-xe2-and-delphi-2009)

That means that blindly using `WriteConsole` breaks output redirection. If you use `WriteConsole` you should fall back to `WriteFile` like this:

```
var
  NumWritten: Cardinal;
  Bytes: TBytes;
begin
  if not WriteConsole(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), PChar(S), Length(S),
    NumWritten, nil) then
  begin
    Bytes := TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(S);
    WriteFile(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), Bytes[0], Length(Bytes),
      NumWritten, nil);
  end;
  WriteLn;
end;
```

Note that output redirection with any encoding works fine in `cmd.exe`. It just writes the output stream to the file unchanged.

PowerShell however expects either ANSI output or the **correct preamble (/ BOM) has to** be included at the start of the output (or the file will be malencoded!). Also PowerShell will always convert the output into UTF-16 with preamble.

[MSDN recommends](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687401%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) using `GetConsoleMode` to find out if the standard handle is a console handle, also the BOM is mentioned:

> WriteConsole fails if it is used with a standard handle that is
>   redirected to a file. If an application processes multilingual output
>   that can be redirected, determine whether the output handle is a
>   console handle (one method is to call the GetConsoleMode function and
>   check whether it succeeds). If the handle is a console handle, call
>   WriteConsole. If the handle is not a console handle, the output is 
>   redirected and you should call WriteFile to perform the I/O. Be sure to 
>   prefix a Unicode plain text file with a byte order mark. For more
>   information, see Using Byte Order Marks.

Comment: -1 That is not what `WriteConsoleW` does. The Windows console is perfectly capable of writing international characters through `WriteConsoleW`, although it is limited to UCS-2. Add a call to `Writeln(GetConsoleCP)` to the second program in my question and observe that the output is not 65001. Sorry to downvote you, but I felt compelled to do so since what you state is demonstrably wrong.

Comment: When you call `WriteConsoleW`, the former applies. Try this: `SetConsoleOutputCP(1252); WriteConsole(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), PChar(Text), Length(Text), NumWritten, nil);` Note that the text is output correctly even though the characters are not present in the output codepage.

Comment: That's true enough. `WriteConsoleW` is clearly doing significant work.

Comment: I've rewritten my answer to reflect my research.