# Unicode in console

Tags: delphi, console, delphi-10.3-rio

How do I write Unicode characters in a console window? I've Googled and the most common answer is either use `UTF8String` or set the Codepage using `SetConsoleOutputCP` but I can't get it to work! The Danish letter ø isn't displaying correctly.

I DID read this question:
[Is Writeln capable of supporting Unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26255148/is-writeln-capable-of-supporting-unicode) and I DID try out the code before posting my own question.

A little test program:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, Winapi.Windows;

var
  HolidayName: String;
begin
  HolidayName := 'Palmesøndag'; // Palm Sunday in Danish
  Writeln(HolidayName);
  Writeln(UTF8String(HolidayName));
  SetConsoleOutputCP(TEncoding.UTF8.CodePage);
  Writeln(HolidayName);
  Readln;
end.
```

And the result is:

[image]

So in short what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I succeeded in getting the desired display by using Lucida Console font (which caused the first two lines to be correct) and changing `TEncoding.UTF8.CodePage` to `CP_UTF8` which fixed the third line.

Comment: @Jens, did you select a font that is unicode compliant ( for example Lucida Console or Consolas)?

Comment: No I'll try that later. I just wondered why it works in c# but not in Delphi