# Delphi 2007 console application writeln() prints garbage

Tags: delphi, console, codepages

My Win10 is setup for Greek codepage, even for programs that don't use Unicode, but the expresion `writeln(TextInGreek)` prints foreign characters.

Following is a reproducable example:

```
program Project5;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

var errorMes : string;

begin
    errorMes := 'αβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρστυφχψω';
    writeln(errorMes); // I receive 'άέήϊίόύϋώΆΈΉΊΌΎΏ±≤ΪΫ÷≈°∙'
    readln;
end.
```

I searched many posts about this, but I didn't find something useful for me.

PS. No success with all bellow sugestions in both Delphi 2007 & 2010

Comment: A [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (example in Python: `'αβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρστυφχψω'.encode( 'cp1253').decode( 'cp737')` returns `'άέήϊίόύϋώΆΈΉΊΌΎΏ±≤ΪΫ÷≈°∙'`). Try changing code page as `chcp 1253` (or `chcp 737`, I'm not sure) _before_ running the app.

Comment: [Change default code page of Windows console to UTF-8](https://superuser.com/q/269818/388890).  This isn't a Delphi problem.  The linked question here is asking about changing the default for the console to UTF-8, but I'm sure you can figure out how to make it 1253 instead - the methods are the same.

Comment: In my PCs cmdline and everywhere I can write Greek  and non Unicode programs work right. Only a delphi console app, like the test one in my first post, writes in console garbages. That seems to be a problem in my Delphi code. Maby I must change codePage to 1253/737 but I don't know the way. Besides this, the app would be run at different PCs so changing something  in my PC is not an option even solves the problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Writeln capable of supporting Unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26255148/is-writeln-capable-of-supporting-unicode)

Comment: My computer has Ukrainian locale. Windows code page for ANSI apps is 1251, but default console codepage is 866. In pre Delphi2009 era I had to manually convert output, but now I simply add "DefaultSystemCodePage := GetConsoleCP;" as the first line of all my console apps.

Comment: @whosrdaddy. No, the problem remains. I tried with Delphi 2007 and 2010. The same. I've abandon the solution with console application.